# Angular-Schema-Form Custom Component number validation issue

Tags: angularjs, angular-schema-form

I have created a custom component which allows user to select mathematical operator for number based searches. It's all working fine apart from the validation. I have included screenshots below to show what I mean, and the relevant part of the model is shown too.

If I enter a number or a non number validation is fine as below.

[image: Validation as expected]

If I enter a number, whilst it does not show an error, it does not show the green highlight:

[image: Valiation right although no green highlight]

Then, if I delete this then it shows null error:

[image]

Other number fields are NOT removed from the model as i expected but rather set to null, which is fine as validation passes. But here, it's not. I notice that it doesn't get added to $$value$$['value'] unless it's a number, whereas in the case of a  normal number field, it's also added when null.

**Can anyone advise on why this might happen how to resolve this please?**

Note: I also don't see these custom components listed under ngForm? Not sure if relevant - perhaps, as i cant manually set pristine...

[image]

EDIT: As requested this is my operators.html template file:

```
<div class="form-group {{form.htmlClass}}" ng-class="{'has-error': hasError()}">

  <div style="height: 45px;!important">

    <label class="control-label" ng-show="showTitle()">{{form.title}}</label>

    <div ng-class="{'input-group': (form.fieldAddonLeft || form.fieldAddonRight)}">
    <span ng-if="form.fieldAddonLeft"
          class="input-group-addon"
          ng-bind-html="form.fieldAddonLeft"></span>

      <input style="float: right; width: 75%; background-color: white; " ng-show="form.key"
             type="number"
             class="form-control"
             schema-validate="form"
             ng-model="$$value$$.value"/>

      <select ng-model="$$value$$.operator" style="float: left; width: 25%;" class="form-control"
              ng-options="operator as operator.label for operator in $parent.$parent.$parent.mappingUsedByDropdown[form.title]">
      </select>

    <span ng-if="form.fieldAddonRight"
          class="input-group-addon"
          ng-bind-html="form.fieldAddonRight"></span>

    </div>
  </div>

  <span class="help-block">{{ (hasError() && errorMessage(schemaError())) || form.description}}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you post your add-on template? The green highligth depends on a ng-class for instance. How do you do the validation?

Comment: David - I have added the template code, thanks.